# jsonnet - remove null values from array

Tags: jsonnet

I want to remove empty values and duplicates from an array, duplicate values are getting removed, empty isn't

template:

```
local sub = [ "", "one", "two", "two", ""];
{
 env: std.prune(std.uniq(std.sort(sub)))
}
```

output:

```
{
  "env": [
    "",
    "one",
    "two"
  ]
}
```

std.prune is supposed to remove empty, null but it is not happening, am I doing something wrong? or is there other way to remove empty values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html#prune

> "Empty" is defined as zero length `arrays`, zero length `objects`, or
>   `null` values.

i.e. `""` is not considered for pruning, you can then use a comprehension as
(note also using `std.set()` as it's literally `uniq(sort())`):

```
local sub = [ "", "one", "two", "two", ""];
{
   env: [x for x in std.set(sub) if x!= ""]
}
```

or `std.length(x) > 0` for that conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std.filter(func,arr) to keep only non empty entries.

> **std.filter(func, arr)**
>
> Return a new array containing all the elements of arr for which the func >function returns true.

You can specify the first parameter to `std.filter` as a function that takes a single parameter and returns true, if the parameter is not `""`. The second parameter is your array.

```
local nonEmpty(x)= x != "";
local sub = [ "", "one", "two", "two", ""];
{
   env: std.uniq(std.filter(nonEmpty,sub))
}
```

You can also define it inline:

```
local sub = [ "", "one", "two", "two", ""];
{
   env: std.uniq(std.filter(function(x) x != "",sub))
}
```

This removes empty values from the array and yields:

```
> bin/jsonnet fuu.jsonnet 
{
   "env": [
      "one",
      "two"
   ]
}
```